# full width responsive BP grid

Tags: grid

I'm using http://responsivebp.com/css/grid/ grid and i´m having troubles. How do i go full width here? I'm going nuts :D

```
<div class="container">

  <header class="col-l-12">

    <div id="logo" class="col-l-4">
      <img src="" alt=""></img>
      <h1>Bedrijfsnaam</h1>
      <p>Diensten - Porducten</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-l-6" id="slogan"><h3>Bedrijfslogan kan hier geplaatst worden</h3></div>

    <div id="contact" class="col-l-2">
      <a href="#">tel nummer</a>
      <a href="#">emain@adress.com</a>
    </div>

 </header>


<nav class="col-l-12">
    <ul>
      <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product ontwikkeling</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ontwinkeling diensten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product testen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bedrijfs nieuws</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
</div>


<div class="container-full">
  <p>I NEED TO BE FULL WIDTH...</p>
</div>
```

see my trial here: http://codepen.io/shiva112/pen/GoqbLo

the background of the header and footer need to be full width.

Comment: never mind.... i made body width 90%.. i'm dumb :D fixed it..

Comment: Had you set your body to to 90% or did changing to 90% fix it?